# Trying to derive a contradiction with this simple inequality,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I am stuck at

$$(a+d)^2 - 4(ad-bc) < 0$$
$$\implies (a+d)^2<4(ad-bc)$$
$$\implies (a+d)<2\sqrt{ad-bc}$$

where $a,b,c,d \ge 0$.

Is there a contradiction to derive here?

Also, the square root on the R.H.S. may not be legit, since I don't have any more information about the relation of $ad$ and $bc$ -- so let's say I took the *complex* square root, to be safe.

(This lack of information also makes it hard to use the AM-GM inequality.)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: First of all, comparing complex number does not make sense. Second, that equality should hold for every $a,b,c,d \ge 0$? If so, then you can derive a contradiction since you can take $b,c$ very big and the LSH will stay constant while the RHS will get to $0$ (assuming the square root will stay positive). For example take $b=c=\sqrt {ad}$ and you get $a+d < 0$ which is false. But you really should give more info on the question

Comment: Can't answer, so I put it in a comment. Your last implication is incorrect. Should be $$(a+d)^2<4(ad-bc) \implies |a+d| < 2\sqrt{ad-bc}$$ which is $$0\le (a+d)<2\sqrt{ad-bc}\ \ \text{ OR}\ \ 0\ge (a+d)>-2\sqrt{ad-bc}$$

Comment: @User001 No, I can't undo the downvotes. I will undo your defacement of the question. [**Don't deface your questions.**] I must admit I'm a bit amused that your attempted destruction of your question has caused you to accumulate some more downvotes.

Comment: @CiaPan The question assumes $a,b,c,d\ge0$. So the second case does not really show up.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Ah, right, I must have overlooked that assumption.

Comment: @User001 You are mistaken. Voting is a sacred privilege here, and site moderators can neither see who voted on each post nor remove votes on posts. An automated vote-fraud script runs once each day. Presumably this caught your previous votes. I know nothing of why others have chosen to downvote you, nor have I paid attention to why your other question was marked as a duplicate. I am removing your comments from this question, as they are off-topic. If you feel you are being treated unfairly, you can use the `contact us` link at the bottom of the page to communicate directly with the SE team.

Comment: @User001: What my fellow (and more experienced!) moderator said. The site is first and foremost community moderated. Also, your question is unclear, because nowhere is it stated what exactly you want to prove. After putting in the effort I can make an educated guess that it is the converse of the inequality in the first line. But, many users here don't want to guess what the question is - they want you to tell them that in unmistakable terms. I am somewhat proud about my guessing ability, so I didn't downvote the question. But it looks like the community wants to send you a signal here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex numbers are not ordered, that is, we can't say one complex number is larger than another.

For example $3<4i$ doesn't make any sense in the complex numbers.

Thus, once you take the "complex" square root the inequality doesn't hold anymore.

Comment: ah, good point.  then, backing up to line no. 2, do you see a contradiction?

Comment: i probably have to proceed another way with my problem...

Answer (score 2):

$(a+d)^2-4 (a d-b c)=$ $a^2+2 a d+d^2-4a d+4 b c=$ $a^2-2 a d+d^2+4 b c=$ $=(a-d)^2+4 b c\geq  4 b c\geq 0.$